# Trouble with PySerial read

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, imu

I'm trying to read data from an Arduino serial monitor, but I'm having problems with pyserial's readline function. Here's the simple code which prints to the monitor:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("helloWorld");
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

And here's the Python code I'm using to read the printed output:

```
import serial
arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial()
arduinoSerialData.port = "COM4"
arduinoSerialData.baudrate = 19200
arduinoSerialData.timeout = 1
arduinoSerialData.setDTR(False)
#arduinoSerialData.setRTS(False)
arduinoSerialData.open()
while(True):
    b = arduinoSerialData.readline().decode('utf-8').strip().split(',')
    print(b)
```

This is the error:

```
  File "SerialRead.py", line 11, in <module>
    str_b = b.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

I have no clue what could be going wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you for your time!

Comment: What exactly is the Arduino sending out the serial port?  Nothing is shown in the code you posted.

Comment: @jasonharper Sorry, I left out a line by mistake. It should be fixed now, but the error is still coming up.

Answer (score 1):

I have this code, and this is perfect:

```
import serial

Ser=serial.Serial(port='com8',baudrate='9600',timeout=1)

while True:
    print(Ser.readline())
```

Convert this data to string, and remove uneccesary character.
Example:

```
import serial

Ser=serial.Serial(port='com8',baudrate='9600',timeout=1)

while True:
    data=Ser.readline()
    data=str(data)
    try:
        dat1=data.replace("b","")
        dat2=dat1.replace("\r\n","")
        dat3=dat2[:-5]
        dat4=dat3.replace("'", "")
        print(dat4)
    except:
        print("ERROR: replace method error")
```

Good luck!